# spark driver memory issue on ML pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

i am running logisticregression pipeline and on this line:

```
model = pipeline.fit(train_data)
```

i get the following error repeatedly in the RDDLossFunction stage:

> File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 132, in fit
>     File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 109, in _fit
>     File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 132, in fit
>     File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 288, in _fit
>     File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 285, in _fit_java
>     File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in **call**
>     File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
>     File "/usr/spark-2.3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23199.fit.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 9 tasks (3.4 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (3.0 GB)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>           at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2124)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(RDD.scala:1092)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1086)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1155)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1131)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.loss.RDDLossFunction.calculate(RDDLossFunction.scala:61)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.loss.RDDLossFunction.calculate(RDDLossFunction.scala:47)
>           at breeze.optimize.CachedDiffFunction.calculate(CachedDiffFunction.scala:23)
>           at breeze.optimize.FirstOrderMinimizer.calculateObjective(FirstOrderMinimizer.scala:55)
>           at breeze.optimize.FirstOrderMinimizer.initialState(FirstOrderMinimizer.scala:48)
>           at breeze.optimize.FirstOrderMinimizer.iterations(FirstOrderMinimizer.scala:89)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:798)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:488)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:278)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

i have tried lowering the partition number from 2001 to 400 , as suggested in https://translate.google.co.il/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://bourneli.github.io/scala/spark/2016/09/21/spark-driver-maxResultSize-puzzle.html&prev=search  , but got the same error .
tried also increasing the spark.driver.maxResultSize to 3g - no good also .

i have 2 pipelines , one for preparing the data , that is done on the whole dataset , and the second the include just the LogisticRegression & labelconverter (IndexToString) - is the one that is failing .

i am running on a standalone cluster, 3 workers , with 140GB combined, one master with 15GB.

Answer (score 0):

The error log clearly says `Total size of serialized results of 9 tasks (3.4 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (3.0 GB)`

Have you tried to change `spark.driver.maxResultSize` bigger than 3.4 G?

Comment: yes, of course , but i had to enlarge it twice , and it seems strange considering the data itself is much smaller than the one written in the log .
i have read somewhere that spark keeps state files , and they are the reason for this huge files transfered to the driver .
the question is if there is a way to avoid it .